# unix command to extract lines with blank values in particular position in a fixed width file

Tags: unix, flat-file

I have a fixed width file with no delimiter.
I would like to extract lines in the fixed width file which has blank values from position 550-552

Comment: Does this, by any chances, answer your question: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/32170/find-all-lines-in-a-file-with-a-certain-character-at-a-certain-position ?

Comment: You could try to [Match pattern on a particular position with grep](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/122760/).

Answer (score 1):

With `sed`:

```
sed -nE '/^.{549}[[:blank:]]{3}/p' file
```

The `[[:blank:]]` characters are spaces or tabs, change it to a space character if you want to match three spaces.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `egrep` (or equivalently, `grep -E`):

```sh
#first let's build a test file, using seq to make 549 dummy characters (X), then 3 characters, then some more dummy characters (Y):
laptop:~/tmp$ (for n in `seq 1 549`; do echo -n X;done ;echo -n '   '; echo YYYYYYYYYYYYY ) > file
laptop:~/tmp$ (for n in `seq 1 549`; do echo -n X;done ;echo -n 'zzz'; echo YYYYYYYYYYYYY ) >> file
laptop:~/tmp$ (for n in `seq 1 549`; do echo -n X;done ;echo -n '   '; echo YYYYYYYYYYYYY ) >> file
laptop:~/tmp$ (for n in `seq 1 549`; do echo -n X;done ;echo -n '123'; echo YYYYYYYYYYYYY ) >> file

#then do the actual search
laptop:~/tmp$ egrep '.{549}   ' file
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX   YYYYYYYYYYYYY
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX   YYYYYYYYYYYYY
```